# Web-based bookmark-storage via own webserver?

Tags: php, bookmark, web, apache, lamp

I'm running Linux at home (and on an external VPS) and it would be trivial to installing the LAMP-stack (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) on any of them...  I'm looking for a web-based bookmark handling system, which I can host on my own computer - some PHP-package.

I'm especially looking for something letting me mark bookmarks with tags/keywords, and lets me organize them in a folders-subfolders structure (and it would be extra great if it was possible to let one bookmark-entry, be part of several folders-subfolders).  Adding my own description and comments would be great, as would an ability to search for bookmarks by tags, description or comment.  It would also be great if it tracked the sites I used often (by going to them from the links), and maybe had a list/cloud of favorite sites accordingly.

Anyway, are there any good bookmark-managers that you can run on your own LAMP-stack?  And are there anyone with similar features to what I described?

Comment: That's basically what ownCloud users request for years now: oc has a bookmark app, but lacks the folder structure. Wallabag sounds interesting (more a read-it-later kind of webapp), but again no folder structure. Hoping for something like that as well, so I'm curious for the recommendations you might get!

Comment: For firefox read this https://docs.services.mozilla.com/howtos/run-sync-1.5.html   It might be useful.

Comment: There is an export to html option is chrome, but you would have to design a web form to accept the upload, and a backend to decode and store the info, not easy.